# Filter in range of two date fields

Tags: django, django-filter

I have something like this:

```
 class Model(models.Model):
      start = models.DateTimeField()
      end = models.DateTimeField()
```

and I want to get all models that follow the following constraints:

given two query parameters qstart, qend

- model.end > qstart
- model.start < q.end

which would give all Model objects that lie between in the range of the two dates. I saw you can do

```
 Model.objects.filter(date__range=[qstart, qend])
```

however, that operates on a single field, where as I need to operate on 2 separate fields.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Adapted from Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/)

**filter()**

filter(**kwargs)

Returns a new QuerySet containing objects that match the given lookup parameters. Multiple parameters are joined via AND in the underlying SQL statement.

In your case:

```
Model.objects.filter(start__lte=qend, end__gte=qstart)
```

**Chaining filters**

The result of refining a QuerySet is itself a QuerySet, so it’s possible to chain refinements together. In your case, for example:

```
Model.objects.filter(
     end__gte=qstart
).filter(
     start__lte=qend
)
```

This takes the initial QuerySet of all entries in the database, adds a filter, then another filter. The final result is a QuerySet containing all entries with end > qstart and start < qend.

**Q objects**

If you need to execute more complex queries (for example, queries with OR statements), you can use Q objects.

Q() objects make it possible to define and reuse conditions. Q objects can be combined using the & and | operators. When an operator is used on two Q objects, it yields a new Q object.

In your case:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Model.objects.get(
    Q(end__gte=qstart) & Q(start__lte=qend)
)
```

Comment: You should cite the source (in this case [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/)) if you copy-pasting that to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just add additional condition:

```
Model.objects.filter(start__lte=qend, end__gte=qstart)
```

Where `qend`, `qstart` must be `datetime.date` [objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

Comment: Also datetime.datetime object is applicable in this case

Answer (score 1):

Use simply:

```
Model.objects.filter(end__gte=qstart).filter(start__lte=qend).all()
```

Comment: You don't really need to do `.all()` as `filter()` would already return `QuerySet` also you could combine the logic to perform one query instead of executing two, which might not be as efficient.

Comment: @LaurynasTamulevičius QuerySet is lazy, so adding ``.all()`` does not change anything. There is no additional query, so skipping this has no performance impact. I would compare such a call to writing a comment that indicates the programmer's intentions.

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
start_date = datetime.date(2005, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2005, 3, 31)
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#range